# Virtuemart: get PDF invoice link on order_done step

Tags: joomla2.5, virtuemart

I have Joomla 2.5.17 an Virtuemart 2.0.26d. I want the PDF invoice download link on the order_done step which is rendered by order_done.php view.
I already configured the virtuemart so the order status is on "CONFIRMED" - "C" meaning as the order is paced, the PDF invoice had been already generated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i got it. So this is what you have to do if you want the download link in order_done step. Assuming your PDFs are stored in "media/vmfiles/invoices/" you need to add some code to components/com_virtuemart/controllers/cart.php line about 477 where "else if($task=='confirm')" block starts:

```
        ...
        $cart->confirmDone();
        $view = $this->getView('cart', 'html');

        $securePath = VmConfig::get('forSale_path',0);
        $segments = explode('/', $securePath);
        $folderOnServer = $segments[sizeof($segments)-3].'/'.$segments[sizeof($segments)-2];

        $orderModel = VmModel::getModel('orders');
        $invoiceId = $orderModel->getInvoiceNumber($cart->virtuemart_order_id);
        $pdfName = "{$folderOnServer}/invoices/vminvoice_{$invoiceId}.pdf";

        $view->setLayout('order_done');
        $view->pdfName = $pdfName;
        $view->display();
        ...
```

also a bit code in view templates/{yourtheme}/html/com_virtuemart/cart/order_done.php:

```
<div class="get-pdf"><?php echo JText::_('get_your_pdf'); ?> <a href="<?php echo $this->pdfName; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo JText::_('DOWNLOAD_PDF') ?> </a><br/></div>
```